# Tracking the movement of fingers among RectTransform with touches on the screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, click, touch

I have two rectTransform fields that divide the screen into two parts. Through them, I track touches on the smartphone screen. I want to make it so that when I tap on the field on the left, when I move my finger across the screen, the field on the right does not react to the movement of this finger, but only reacts if you click on it on the right side with another finger. I tried to use fingerId but couldn't get it to work. Is there any way?